# Updating TextView in custom loading dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to update the content of the TextView from "Loading.." to "Getting ready" after three seconds. Any advice on how to achieve this?

Thats my Loading Dialog.

```
public class LoadingDialog {

    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    LoadingDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    void startLoadingDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.document_request_loading, null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        
    }

    void dismissStartLoadingDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you
make timer change in your main thread

```
public class LoadingDialog {

    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
TextView tView;

    LoadingDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    void startLoadingDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.document_request_loading, null);
tView=view.findViewById(R.id.tView);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        
    }
void changeTextLoading(String string){
if(tView!=null){
tView.setText(string);
}
}

    void dismissStartLoadingDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does what I needed to. I never thought of just trying to change textView... The lack of my experience is showing.

Comment: If you have got this right please accept my answer